# Remove square brackets [] from Array in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the date with square brackets **[2014-11-08 06:27:00.0]**, and a want remove it.

Expected output is **2014-11-08 06:27:00.0**

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").setAppName("CasteDate").setMaster("local[*]")
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
   .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
   .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val csc=new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

var input: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
input.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
var dia: SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
var mes: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM")
var ano: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
var horas: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH")
var minutos: SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("mm")

val data=csc.sql("SELECT timecol from smartgrids.analyzer_temp").collect()

import sqlContext.implicits._

val result = data.map(row => {
                         val day = dia.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val month = mes.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val year = ano.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val hour = horas.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                         val minute = minutos.format(input.parse(row.toString()))
                             })

val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("day", 2), ("month", 2), ("year", 4), ("hour", 2), ("minute", 2)))
collection.saveToCassandra("features", "datepart", SomeColumns("day", "month", "year", "hour", "minute"))
sc.stop()
```

After execute this code i receive the error:

```
   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "[2015-08-20 21:01:00.0]" 
   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

I think that this error is because the date have square brackets, so, i want remove it.

Comment: And, what problem are you having with your current approach?

Comment: What type do you have/want, a `String`?

Comment: I added my code at question, so it may be easier to understand what I'm trying to do. 

After run the code I get an array of dates, when map these dates, I want to remove the  square brackets.

Comment: Check available methods on String that remove a char, remove a prefix/suffix, or the substring method

Comment: "dia,mes,horas,minutos" - don't do that man ... imagine if you would inherit code written by a Chinese man/woman ...

Comment: possible cause is this [see kode answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314691/647053) instead of row.toString()  row.getAs[String] will not give square braces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [collect on a dataframe spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313929/collect-on-a-dataframe-spark)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.replaceAll` and a regular expression to remove the unwanted characters.

```
str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
```

would remove opening and closing square brackets from a String.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the following:

```
val result = data.map(row => {
    val day = dia.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))  
    val month = mes.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))                                       
    val year = ano.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))                                        
    val hour = horas.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))                                     
    val minute = minutos.format(input.parse(row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")))
})
```

I tested it and it works.

input date:

```
  data: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([2015-08-20 21:01:00.0]
```

output:

```
  Array(List(20, 08, 2015, 21, 01)
```

Comment: Tip: `string.replace` accepts a regular expression. You could replace all characters at once instead of chaining on `.replace.replace.replace...`

Comment: Glad it works, but it's terribly verbose. If you're just removing all characters of a certain set, why not just filter them out? In other words: `...toString().filterNot("[]()".contains(_))`

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

dataset.select("id").distinct.as[String].collect prints as string array if you are using Spark 2.0