# collect on a dataframe spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I wrote this:

```
df.select(col("colname")).distinct().collect.map(_.toString()).toList
```

the result is

```
List("[2019-06-24]", "[2019-06-22]", "[2019-06-23]")
```

Whereas I want to get :

```
List("2019-06-24", "2019-06-22", "2019-06-23")
```

How to change this please

Comment: this is not scala syntax

Comment: Please explain why you would expect your code to give the expected result, and include a bit more info. For instance, the schema of the dataframe in question, as well as some test data.

Comment: @DavisBroda : I think what scalacode has posted is right. see the answers below

Comment: this question is basically difference between  about Row.toString and Row.getAs[String] where op used toString and he is getting square braces. @kode has corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `.map(_.toString())` to `.map(_.getAs[String]("colname"))`.
With `.map(_.toString())`, you are calling `org.apache.spark.sql.Row.toString`, that's why the output is like `List("[2019-06-24]", "[2019-06-22]", "[2019-06-23]")`.
Correct way is:
`val list = df.select("colname").distinct().collect().map(_.getAs[String]("colname")).toList`
Output will be:

```
List("2019-06-24", "2019-06-22", "2019-06-23")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(("2019-06-24"),( "2019-06-22"),("2019-06-23"))).toDF("cn")
```

Now **select column** then apply **`map`** to get **first index value** then **add quotes** and convert to string.

```
df.select("cn").collect().map(x => x(0)).map(x => s""""$x"""".toString)
//res36: Array[String] = Array("2019-06-24", "2019-06-22", "2019-06-23")
```

(or)

```
df.select("cn").collect().map(x => x(0)).map(x => s""""$x"""".toString).toList
//res37: List[String] = List("2019-06-24", "2019-06-22", "2019-06-23")
```